# Where is the openJDK console window?

Tags: java, applet, openjdk

I am used to java-sun JDK on windows and its console: It is very convenient to debug an applet. Is there such console with open-jdk on ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the messages of the console during an applet execution, it is enough to launch the Internet navigator in a terminal. The output message will display there.

Comment: Works with firefox. Just start firefox from the console and the output from iced-tea is shown there.

Comment: I have started firefox in a windos cmd shell and see no console output.